# My php file deleted automatically from c panel

Tags: php

Hey friends in my hosting my base_facebook.php file is deleted continuously I talked with customer care he says that hosting antivirus detected your file as a virus but same file I tried to other hosting and it is fine what I do? 
What is the problem in my file and how to fix [this](http://jioliker.com)

[Here is my file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Ibh3LNs0DSVWhhbkVFa2RPMDQ/view?usp=drivesdk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That first piece of code in your `base_facebook.php` is malicious. Remove it!

[image]

**EDIT**

This file is needed for your facebook application(if any) to work! Either remove that piece of code(which I marked in red) from your file or replace the whole file. Based on the version number, it seems to be v3.1.1.

When searched for a copy of this file, I found this: https://github.com/uiri/feedview/blob/master/base_facebook.php

I think you are using an old Facebook SDK(v3.1.1), which I think they officially don't support(or its depreciated)

Comment: After removing my file will work properly or not ....

Comment: This file is needed for your facebook application(if any) to work! Either remove that piece of code(which I marked in red) from your file or replace the whole file. Based on the version number, it seems to be v3.1.1. When searching, I found this copy: https://github.com/uiri/feedview/blob/master/base_facebook.php